# Split point shapefile by date attribute using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, point, splitting

I have a point shapefile composed of points created on a Garmin in 2012 and 2013.  They are in the format mm/dd/yyyy (there are other fields, but this is the one of interest).  I was wondering if there was a way that I could split them from one shapefile into two (one with all 2012 dates, one with all 2013 dates).

Could I just create another field and label it "1" for all the 2012 points and "2" for the 2013 points, and then split by attribute and delete the field when finished?

Which tool can I use?

Comment: Can't you just select in ArcMap all the points with the 2012 year and right click on the layer to export to a new shapefile; then repeat the selection and export for 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create an extra field to do this. The workflow in Arcgis desktop is as the following:

1- Make a selection (Dates Over 2013) and export to a separate shape file.

2- Revert the selection and export to a separate shape file.

Snapshots in ArcGIS:
[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]